# Net Core: How to create CSS with TagBuilder?

Tags: c#, css, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I use Tag Builder CSS Class?

I want to incorporate this in a style class

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
background-color:white;
}

TagBuilder image = new TagBuilder("img");
```

How would I then add the attributes?

Comment: Are you talking about adding a class to the tag that has those styles attached to it or to write these inside the style attribute?

Comment: adding inside style attribute

Comment: actually both ways would be nice however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm just going to demonstrate an example for this here. I am not using the styles or the context provided, just doing a sample in two different ways.
In the example provided here, I have two custom tags.[image]

And I am add the following style rules.

```
<style>
    .black-div {
        height:40px;
        width: 40px;
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

These are the two tag helpers that correspond to the tags provided previously.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div-with-class")]
public class ClassTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "black-div");
    }
}
[HtmlTargetElement("div-with-style")]
public class StyleTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("style", "height:40px;width: 40px;background-color: black;");
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your css styles in a css class in your root css file.

```
<style>
.myImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
```

The use below code to add the css class:

```
TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("img");
builder.AddCssClass("myImage");
builder.MergeAttribute("src", url);
builder.MergeAttribute("alt", "AltImage");
```